# Interval order(s) and the empty interval

Tags: order-theory

I am working with the set of half-closed intervals (lower-bound is closed, upper-bound is open) and gleefully defined two interval order: the $≤$ partial order and the $<$ strict partial order.

The problem is that my set of intervals include the empty interval and I don't know what is the natural way of defining those orders on that empty interval without breaking any partial order rules.

If I accept all of the following (for $a < b$):

- $∅ ≠ [a,b)$
- $[a,b) ≤ ∅$
- $∅ ≤ [a,b)$

then I break the asymmetry rule. What is the standard way of dealing with this?

Maybe I can dissymetrize this way:

$$S ≤ T \iff \forall x∈S, \exists y∈T,~ x ≤ y$$

But then I lose $∅ ≤ ∅$ which breaks the antisymmetry rule.

Comment: Actually, all I need is a *strict weak ordering* so that might work.

Comment: That is $S < T \iff \forall x ∈ S, \forall y ∈ T,~ x < y$ is (probably?) a *strict weak order*. (nope, not irreflexive for $∅$)

Comment: I would probably make the empty interval incomparable to all others.  That is, $\emptyset \le \emptyset$, and $\emptyset \not\le [a,b)$, $[a,b) \not\le \emptyset$.

Comment: I don’t understand the last sentence in the question. If you define $S\le T$ as $\forall x\in S\,\exists y\in T\,x\le y$, then $\emptyset\le\emptyset$ is true. And in fact, $\emptyset\le T$ for any $T$.

Comment: Note that for nonempty $S$ and $T$, this definition is equivalent to $\sup(S)\le\sup(T)$. I’m not sure if this is a useful comparison of intervals, as it does not depend on the lower bounds. Actually, it also fails to be antisymmetric, as it makes all intervals with the same upper bound equivalent.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek you are correct. That definition is not useful. I'm guessing the only meaningful way to proceed is, as NateEldredge suggests, to simply exclude the empty interval all together.

Comment: I don’t know if it suits your application, but another way to proceed may be to abandon the idea that there is *the* empty interval, and that intervals are sets of points (just like in synthetic geometry, lines are primitive objects, not sets of points). If you change the setup so that intervals are primitive objects with defined end-points, you can consider $[a,a)$ and $[b,b)$ for $a\ne b$ to be distinct intervals (even though they are both “empty”). I think that then you can define interval order in a more coherent way even on the empty intervals.